# Get tweet from especific user from tweet

Tags: azure, twitter

I am trying to replicate an example in which explain how to receive information from twitter, through azure.

the example is as follows [example link](https://stefanroth.net/2016/02/21/azure-automation-twitter-ifttt-webhook-start-runbook/)

The code used in the example is:

#### runbook

```
    param (
 [object]$WebhookData
 )

if ($WebhookData -ne $null) 
    {
        $BodyContent = $WebhookData.RequestBody
        Write-Output "There was a tweet from $BodyContent"
    }
else
    {
        Write-Error "Something went wrong buddy"   
    }
```

#### webhook

```
$Credential = Get-Credential

#Authenticate to Azure and AzureRM
Add-AzureAccount -Credential $Credential | Out-Null
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $Credential | Out-Null

#Provide the necessary information for your environment
$Webhook = New-AzureRmAutomationWebhook `
 -Name "TriggeredByTwitter"`
 -RunbookName "Hello-Twitter"`
 -IsEnabled 1 `
 -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddDays(10)`
 -ResourceGroupName "Automation"`
 -AutomationAccountName "AutomationAccount"

#Print the webhook uri
Write-Host $Webhook.WebhookUri -ForegroundColor Green
```

At the time of creating a webhook, applying a variable, but I think this is where the problem lies.

I would like to know how to use a variable that allows me, and that type must be to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the instructions and they seem to work. What I did was:

**Create the Automation account, runbook and add some contents to the runbook**

1) Log in to https://portal.azure.com

2) Add a new Automation account. Wait until it's done.

[image: Create Automation Account]

3) Create a new PowerShell runbook inside the Automation account

[image: Create a runrook]

4) Once it's ready, navigate to it inside of the Azure portal and edit its contents. There add as it's contents

```
Write-Host "Hello World!"
```

4) Save & Publish the runbook.

5) While inside the runbook, open the "Test pane"

[image: Save, publish and start the runbook]

6) Press "Start" and it should print out "Hello World!".

[image: Running the Hello world runbook]

**Create the webhook**

7) Go back to the runbook and press the "Webhook" button.

8) Press the "Add webhook" button to add a new webhook

9) Give the webhook a name and leave rest of the settings. They are fine like that for testing :) Before you press OK, take note of the URL it presents you. Press OK.

10) Press Create.

[image: New webhook]

**Testing the webhook**

11) Go back to the runbook, put it in edit more, and go to the "Test pane"

12) Open, e.g. the Chrome extension Postman or navigate to https://www.hurl.it and test out the webhook.

13) Make a POST request to the URL you were presents with when creating the webhook.

[image]

14) Go back to the automation account and watch the monitoring section. There should soon appear a request. When you open the latest request you can see the output from it

**Pass data to the webhook**

15) Modify the script to read

```
Param
(
    [object] $webhookdata
)

Write-Output "Hello World! - $($webhookdata.RequestBody)"
```

Save and publish the script

16) Go back to hurl.it and add some body to the request.

[image: POST with body]

17) Now go back to the monitoring section and you should be able to see the result

[image: Webhook with a body]

18) If you have a look at the data it passed to the script. There are also other parameters you can read

```
{"WebhookName":"testwh","RequestBody":"Test","RequestHeader":{"Accept":"*/*","Accept-Encoding":"gzip","Host":"s9events.azure-automation.net","User-Agent":"runscope/0.1","x-ms-request-id":"3955cc96-34c5-409b-94c5-19ec37e07c49"}}
```

Comment: I have a question, i can use the same runbook, for the get tweet, i can't create the webhook, i need custom values

Comment: I improved a bit on the answer and added more instructions on how to get data read from the request sent to the webhook.

Comment: When use `Write-Hots "Hello World"`, dont display anything, [image-1](http://imgur.com/a/pplYw), but when use `Write-Hots "Hello World"`, display the message [image-2](http://imgur.com/a/Yf3Jv)

Comment: Here [image output fine](http://imgur.com/a/6WS5q), [image output wrong](http://imgur.com/a/ZT5LT)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but dont work for me, show me ok all, but dont show result from the **Postman** or **Hurl**

Comment: After you made a POST request, go find the same request from the monitoring section, see 17) above for which screen I mean. There have a look at the "Input" button. In the above screenshot there's written "2" ontop of it and it's encircled with a red box. Look at what the json contains, you should find there the body from your POST request. If the body is missing then there's something wrong with your POST request. Otherwise you need to debug your PowerShell script that the runbook is running.

Comment: Thanks, i try all, but i do it again